# How can I disable the “News and Interests” Widget on the Windows 10 Taskbar?

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, windows-10-v1909, widgets

On Windows 10 version 1909 and newer releases, Microsoft has added a "News and Interests" widget on the Taskbar (see [blogpost](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2021/04/22/personalized-content-at-a-glance-introducing-news-and-interests-on-the-windows-10-taskbar/)):

[image]

How can I remove this Widget from the Taskbar?

Comment: A Group Policy approach: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/group-configuration-news-and-interests-on-the-windows-taskbar/ba-p/2281005?s=09

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can disable the “News and Interests” Widget feature by:

1. Right-Click the Taskbar
2. Select "News and Interests"
3. Select "Turn off".

[image]

---

The above method disables it, however, if you right-click the Taskbar, you will still see an option "News and interests", If you want to fully remove it, you can use the Registry:

Save the following with a ".reg" extension and run it, restart your File Explorer or restart your computer to apply:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Feeds]
"EnableFeeds"=dword:00000000
```

To re-enable the Widget, save the following with a ".reg" extension and run it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Feeds]
"EnableFeeds"=-
```

Credit: [Shawn Brink from TenForums](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/178178-how-enable-disable-news-interests-taskbar-windows-10-a.html)