# How can I remove the new weather information from the taskbar?

Tags: windows-10

After the last Windows update ([21H1](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/it-tools-to-support-windows-10-version-21h1/ba-p/2365103)), I got this weather icon on the taskbar and clicking on it shows the news, weather and traffic information.

How can I remove it?

[image: Weather icon on the taskbar1]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I disable the “News and Interests” Widget on the Windows 10 Taskbar?](https://superuser.com/questions/1649169/how-can-i-disable-the-news-and-interests-widget-on-the-windows-10-taskbar)

Comment: I found [this](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/disable-the-news-and-interests-widget-on-the-windows-10-taskbar/) as a first search result after installing update. Didn't associate "weather" with "news and interests" as the dozens of other users it seems, thanks to microsofts wording.

Comment: A Group Policy approach: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/group-configuration-news-and-interests-on-the-windows-taskbar/ba-p/2281005?s=09

Answer (score 47, accepted):

> After the last Windows update, I got weather icon on the taskbar and
> clicking on it shows some celeb news and traffic info

That is the [News and interests](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/stay-up-to-date-with-news-and-interests-a39baa08-7488-4169-9ed8-577238f46f8f) taskbar widget.

To turn it off:

- Right-click on the taskbar, select `News and Interests`, then click `Turn off`:

[image]

You can also disable the "News and interests" taskbar widget in Group Policy using either of these methods:

- In `Computer Configuration > Administative Templates > Windows Components > News and interests` set the policy `Enable news and interests on the taskbar` to `Disabled`.
- Registry (open cmd as admin)

  - `REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Feeds" /V EnableFeeds /T REG_DWORD /D 0 /F`

You'll need to kill explorer.exe and relaunch it or reboot for the policy to apply.

Comment: Can you also uninstall it? Is there the risk that after some updates or configuration changes it is reactivated if it is not uninstalled?

Comment: There is a powershell script here:  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/forum/bing_apps-bing_install-bing_appdev_win8/remove-news-feed-from-task-bar/6ec30157-33a8-4908-9363-a25e74bf0677?auth=1   but there is probably more risk it will be reinstalled instead of just re-enabled.

Comment: @FluidCode - This particular feature cannot be uninstalled.  However, Taskbar settings are respected, once disabled, it should be enabled with an update.  You can just [disable](https://www.neowin.net/news/how-to-turn-off-the-news-and-interest-widget-on-taskbar-in-windows-10/) through the group policy.  (I don’t submit actual answers based on questions asked within a temporary comment

Comment: It gets re-activated with every update. I maintain seven machines, and all of them have it back on after each update... same if you de-install it, it comes back. Microsoft...

Comment: It will get fixed.  I have done both production and Insider updates and it is not returning. Once you are fully up to date it should be fine.

Comment: @John that powershell script removes just one key from the registry. If it were only one group of keys you could remove them manually, but I suspect that things are a little bit more complex than that.

Comment: @FluidCode I have flagged this question as a duplicate. In the provided link, I have posted an answer how to fully remove it.

Comment: @MendelG I had a look at the linked question and I found again a simple hack for a single registry key. Did I miss something? I still suspect that thing are actually more complex than that.

Comment: I am suspected it's implicatedin the random complete disapperance of my taskbar. Now you see it, now you don't... I oculd be wrong though.

Comment: @Aganju - It should not be enabled after the next feature, note my original comment had a typo when it said it should be enabled; In either case the GPO will keep it disabled permanently

Comment: @John What software do you use to take your screenshots?

Comment: Stuff that pops up (as the screen shot in the post) is best captured with Snip 'n Sketch. It will capture a open window flyout where SnagIt will usually not. But when I complete the capture, SnagIt takes over and I edit the final image in SnagIt.  SnagIt editing is more polished than Snip 'n Sketch.