# How to stop popup box in bottom right corner of screen (Windows 10)?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, popups

Recently every time I move my cursor anywhere near the bottom-right of my screen an irritating popup with news stories etc. appears above my taskbar. It is very distracting and it obscures my screen so I can't click or read anything in this area of the screen while I am trying to work.

The popup looks like this:

[image: screenshot of popup window in bottom-right of screen]

I can't find an obvious option to deactivate it and Google did not seem to help. Does anyone know how to get rid of it and stop it from appearing?

Comment: That is News and Interests.  Right click on the Task Bar and uncheck News and Interests.   https://superuser.com/questions/1655569/how-can-i-remove-the-new-weather-information-from-the-taskbar/1655571#1655571