# Disable only the news in the News and Interests bar

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

Is there a way to disable the news from Windows' "News and Interests" taskbar tool *without* disabling the weather display?  I find it very useful for weather and traffic, but I'm really not interested in anything else that would show up there.

[This previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/1649169/how-can-i-disable-the-news-and-interests-widget-on-the-windows-10-taskbar) concerns disabling it entirely, but that also removes the weather display.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is an all or nothing arrangement. I turned it on and went to the ... top right and looked at the settings, but it does not appear you can isolate just weather.

Comment: It is indeed an all or nothing feature.

Comment: Disappointing, but not at all surprising.