# Hide notifiction icon that is on that taskbar

Tags: windows-11

This one:

[image]

A similar question:

[How to hide notification icon in system tray on windows 11](https://superuser.com/questions/1702251/how-to-hide-notification-icon-in-system-tray-on-windows-11)

The offered answer suggests a registry patch that may not be valid (and Microsoft is known to release updates that invalidate them on purpose), and I prefer a setting that would persist.

My focus assist is off.

I don't mind if it's hidden in the tray.

Comment: I don't have it on my copy of windows 11. what version exactly do you have?

Comment: I upgraded my win10 yesterday to: Microsoft Windows 11 Education,Version 10.0.22621 Build 22621

Comment: You say the linked answer MAY not be valid. Have you checked?

Comment: I'm not going to add keys to my registry and restart my computer based on answers that aren't vetted, and see my comment about persistent solution.

Comment: However, no harm in googling it, and it seems legit (thanks): https://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-notification-center-in-windows-11

Answer (score 0):

Try System > Notifications: disable notifications and do not disturb.

[image: options menu]

Tested on Windows 11 Education 22H2 build 22621.525

Comment: I have both of these options off. If you turn on either one, then does it appear on the taskbar?

Answer (score -1):

After some incentive from @music2myear:

https://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-notification-center-in-windows-11