# Stop queued replay of Windows notifications while AFK

Tags: windows, windows-11, notifications

TLDR: Notifs get queued when AFK instead of displayed. When I get back, I get a never ending, slow, playback of each notif, one by one.

When I go AFK, and keep getting notifications, those will queue up and then replay back to me when I am back on the computer, over the next few minutes. How do I turn this off?

Context:

For example, I have Slack open, and theres a conversation going. I go AFK but the other members keep chatting. For each message on the channel a new notification is queued up for me, but since I am AFK, those get "saved". Once I get back, I receive the first notification in the queue (not the last), and then those get replayed one by one until none are left. If there was 50 messages in Slack in between me AFKing, then I will slowly get all 50 one by one without about a 30 second interval in between. This takes minutes.

This is absolutely annoying and useless.

In 30 or so seconds, I have scrolled through the messages on the Slack app, but I am still receiving notifications from messages from 10 minutes ago, just as if they were sent now. This is also very confusing, as it seems like you are getting new messages, instead of notifications from messages you already have read.

How can I turn this feature off? I want only the latest notification on screen, let it stay there until I get back so I know something happened.

Maybe even group them by app, I dont mind having the right side of the screen filled with notifications (if they are from individual apps, instead of repeated, the better)

Comment: Are you talking about the notification and action center notifications? Not sure if this will help: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-notification-and-quick-settings-in-windows-ddcbbcd4-0a02-f6e4-fe14-6766d850f294#WindowsVersion=Windows_11. Might be a dupe question here too for multiple solutions: GPO, Registry, etc. https://superuser.com/questions/1702251/how-to-hide-notification-icon-in-system-tray-on-windows-11

Answer (score -1):

To turn off all notifications from the Slack app, do this :

1. Run *Settings > System > Notifications & actions‌*
2. Find Slack in the list below "Get notifications from these apps"
3. Click the blue icon to turn notification off for Slack

Alternatively, you may limit the notifications you receive from Slack by
in step 3:

3. Click on "Slack" itself (not on the blue icon)
4. Set "Number of notifications visible in Action Centre"

(Note : I don't know how well the Slack app obeys these settings.)

Comment: A downvote is useless without an explanation.