# How to turn off the Olympic medal spoiler in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

In Windows 10, there is a taskbar which during the Olympics shows what medals your country achieved today, potentially spoiling if you are not able to watch the events live. What is this feature, and how can it be turned off?

Answer (score 1):

This feature of Windows 10 is called News & Interests. If you right click the taskbar and hover over the "News & Interests" button, there is an option to turn this feature off, as per [How can I disable the “News and Interests” Widget on the Windows 10 Taskbar?](https://superuser.com/questions/1649169/how-can-i-disable-the-news-and-interests-widget-on-the-windows-10-taskbar).